# AWS Performance Insight is logging and showing personal information, how to obfuscate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, query-optimization, amazon-rds, monitoring, aws-documentdb

Currently, I am using performance insight in a non-production environment to analyze the queries and understand them better.

The point is that AWS Performance Insight logs and shows all the data of the queries and these queries show personal data.

Is there any way to don't log the data of the queries? or just obfuscate in many companies this could be a problem.